# Submit SLURM job to multiple accounts

Tags: cluster-computing, scheduler, slurm

I'm a user of a cluster where the workload is managed by slurm. I have access to resources of two accounts (e.g. accounts `X` and `Y`) and want to submit a job to the cluster, but neither of the accounts have free resources to run it currently. Is there a way to specify two accounts for the job so that it can run on any account that gets free first? I tried `--acount=X,Y` but it did not work.